# Wrong h1 color on load, refresh always fix it

Tags: css, colors

Good morning,

I have a problem with titles on my page. When I load it for the first time (with preloader), titles (h1) are black, or gray or some dark color, but they are set to be white. When I just refresh the page (preloader doesn't show), all titles are white. URL http://testovaci.mobydyk.cz/twilightkid/

Could someone please help me, what should be wrong there? I've checked all css files, everywhere is h1 set to color white. Thank you for all advices!

Comment: It does not have that problem. I checked in Chrome version 46.0.2490.80  and Firefox 42.0. What is your browser?

Comment: Same here. On very first visit titles showed white.

Comment: @alirezasafian
I've tried some changes, but now I've got it back, could you try it again please? Just with new opened browser, because of cookies. Thanks! btw I'm using firefox

Comment: oh, it was in cookies, I've deleted them and now it works fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I have the same issue. (chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 m (64-bit))

What is obvious to me is that it's not the CSS files that seem to be wrong, it's rather the HTML.

Look at these two screenshots:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByzbHcAxmCyvcGhOcDRoZFR1cTA
[image]

You can see that the `style="rgb(34,34,34)"` is defined right on the HTML `h1` element.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByzbHcAxmCyvUXJ2UFJUbWh1Tlk
[image]

But here, there isn't any `style` in the HTML element.

So my first guess is that somehow something adds a `style` that define the color for all `h1` elements and it takes priority over your CSS files. It may be JavaScript, I don't know.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've just fixed it! If you are using any preloader or something, check JS files, I've had there, that when the page load, h1 will change color to #222222 and it have saved to cookies. So I have deleted that setting, deleted cookies and now it works :)

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense! Glad to see you fixed it ;)